# How to create an autorelease NSDictionary in this case?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I have a NSMutableArray instance called entries and I would like to send one of its value (which is a NSDictionary) to a method, but I'm thinking of how to avoid it to leak or properly release it. Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
NSDictionary *pdata = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self start_download:pdata];

[pdata release]; // <--> Is it ok to do this ?
```

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should absolutely not release `pdata`, since you never retained it. `-objectAtIndex:` returns a non-owned object. If `-start_download:` needs to refer to `pdata` after it returns (e.g. if it holds onto it for some asynchronous process) then it should retain `pdata` itself, and subsequently it should release `pdata` when it's done, but that's orthogonal to the bit of code you pasted.

If you haven't already done so, you should read the [Cocoa Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

Answer (score 4):

you did not alloc, copy or retain pdata so you don't release it

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a delegate method for start_download to handle with the download finished? You should release it then.

Answer (score 2):

I would have start_download do a retain on pdata and then release it when it's done.  It's always a good idea to have routines that need to hang on to data to a retain and release themselves, that way you don't care how the object got to you and what's going to happen to it after.